# Chrome dev tools confusion in network and performance tab

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I am evaluating my boilerplate:
However, there is some confusion related to time shown in `Network` tab and `Performance` tab.

**Network tab:**

[image]

It tells that blog(.html) was downloaded in `22ms` after the request was resolved by the server, thus taking of total `~51ms`

**Performance tab:**

[image]

It tells that blog(.html) **blue color** started downloading after `~132ms`
and finished at `~199ms` and browser started parsing it afterwards.

**Why is there 2 different things** for the same page refresh(hard refresh infact, though it doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 1):

The Network panel begins a whole new recording when refreshing unless "Preserve Log" is checked. You'll notice the Performance panel is analyzing from the time you hit record. Therefore, it is accounting for the existing analysis on the current page *plus* the new page request.

This is fine and normal behavior. You typically don't need to correlate network panel data with the performance data to that degree. The network request information is provided in Performance primarily as an easy aid to getting the correlation you need between network resources doing their job and the engine carrying forward with tasks because of that.

Comment: I'm not using "Preserve log" as you can also see in screenshot. For Performance tab, I'm NOT manually hitting record button. It automatically when I refresh the page. (I just need to be on performance tab and hit Cmd + R for refresh(or Cmd+Shift+R) and it computes everything again-no manual record button hitting)

Comment: Yup, that's all as expected then. Recording in performance happens right away. the network requests reset when the internals trigger the new pipeline which can be delayed a little.

Comment: There cannot be significant difference. I've checked them independently as well! Whenever I check using `Network`, tab, my first paint(using Capture Screenshots), and other details like load time, stall time, etc, they all are ALWAYS lesser than `Performance` tab consistently. Or if at all, chrome dev tool won't show details at all if there would have been any delay while comparing performance and network tab. May be I am missing something in interpretation. Both `Performance` and `Network` tabs are consistent in their respective details even when checked independently, which proves this thing

Comment: I think it would be best if you provided your use-case for needing them to be perfectly consistent. Without a use-case it seems like nitpicking operational aspects of the DevTools simply because there is some minor inconsistency in the way you see things. When in reality, it doesn't have a big bearing on how the data for each panel is interpreted from what I can tell.

Comment: IMHO, use case of network tab and performance tab is to measure performance. Is there anything more? If I want to make my page load within 600ms second(currently having good connection and it's SSR) then which thing should I consider `Network` / `Performance` tab? Because `Network` tab shows loading within 350-450ms consistently while the same thing is shown as ~700-850ms consistently on `Perf` tab.. As I go on adding stuffs like data fetching, more complex views, what measure would I consider for a website?

Comment: It depends (tm). It's not always you look to one method or the other. I'd say general rule of thumb, if you're analyzing *network* performance use Network. When analyzing overall runtime performance use Performance. Depending on where you're trying to cut things down depends on where you need to look.